# Automatically generate empty lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have no idea how to begin with this, but here's what I need. The user enters a number:

```
n = 3
```

This creates 'n' empty lists:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
```

That is, create 'n' number of lists, based on the input by the user.

This seems like a simple enough problem, and I am sure that I need to create a *for* loop, but I don't know how to go about it.

```
for x in range(n):
    print(list_x = [])
```

But this gives an obvious error:

> 'list_x' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

What I need is a sort of a "Create a list" function, but I don't know what it is.

I am sure there are other ways to solve my problem more elegantly, but I already have a simple solution that works, I just need to create an empty list for each step. I want to now generalize it, so that I don't have to have dozens of lists created at the beginning of the program.

Also, I am a beginner with coding, so please don't be too harsh :)

Comment: Do those lists need to be individual variables? You could generate a list of lists with as many as you need.

Comment: If you have multiple things indexed by a number, think list. If indexed by something else, think dict.

Comment: @Mikael I am not sure if I understand you, but each list needs to be able to hold different elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a dictionary, where each key is the name of the list, and each value contains an empty list.

```
n = 3
dic = {f'list{i}': [] for i in range(1, n+1)}
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'list1': [], 'list2': [], 'list3': []}
```

Comment: What about a list of lists?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure thing, but this approach keeps the naming conventions of lists e.g list_1, list_2, list_3. I was about to edit a default dict approach

Comment: This indeed created a list. 

But how do I access the list (I need to append to it)? I tried to use "list1", and I got an error saying "list1 is not defined"

Comment: @VikrantSrivastava Good question. Type it `dic['list1']`. Mind the quotes. 
The keys are strings therefore it's `'list1'` not `list1` (without quotes).